# How to Pass Arguments/Input To a Bash Command at the Time of its Issuance

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I would like to automate initial installation of a Virtual Private Server (Debian). For that, I'm writing a bash script that issues many commands that sets date, timezone and many other things of this sort. Below is one of them:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

For the above command, I'd like to enter Asia first and then Kolkata.
Is it possible to give something like below while issuing the command?

`printf "Asia\nKolkata" | sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Instead of giving input, each time a command executes, can we take the above action to pass input directly for all commands like this? So that we can run the bash script once and come back at a later time to see the server ready with all the essential software.

Please help.

Comment: I'm sure that some *existing* solution is available. You are reinventing some wheel. When I rented my VPS it was configured wisely and automatically. So your question is really some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I guess that the VPS installation is just copying some master image, and filling a very few files in `/etc/`. Your approach smells bad.

Comment: [feeding input values to dpkg-reconfigure in non-interactive way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96215/feeding-input-values-to-dpkg-reconfigure-in-non-interactive-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that particular case, I won't try to automate `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` but I would instead do the appropriate action (fill `/etc/timezone`  file), much easier to automate with

```
  echo Asia/Kolkata > /etc/timezone
```

BTW, you could consider using [TCL expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/), but I would instead try to automatize the *result* of the configuration.

Maybe you could consider making your own  `.iso` image for your own derivative of Debian. Maybe you need containerization like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Or just identify the files under `/etc/` that need to be configured (there are not that much of them). You could even make your Debian [`.deb` package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) whose installation is filling them (to the same default values you wish).

See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158201/50557) (probably what you really need).

Comment: Hmm. `expect` is what I was about to suggest.. Looks like it is is a must have for the op.

Comment: I believe it is too general for the task. I won't recommend using it in that case.

Comment: For this, yes, it is too general.  But `expect` is one the names that comes to mind when it comes to automation.